# How to make Logstash write internal logs to a file?

Tags: logstash

### Context

I am building a program that will pass an Apache log file into Logstash and output the result (after parsing and filtering) to an external database (Elastic, MongoDB, etc.).

Basically, the program will execute following command:

```
gunzip -c -k "somefile.gz" | logstash -f "logstash.conf"
```

With `logstash.conf` containing:

```
input {
    stdin {}
}
filter {
    # ...
}
output {
    mongodb {
        # ...
    }
}
```

But, to help future debug/forensic, I want to grab whatever Logstash says during it's process.

By default, it seems Logstash outputs it's internal log messages to stdout, as an example, the following command:

```
logstash -e "input { generator { count => 3 } } output { null {} }"
```

Outputs:

```
Sending Logstash's logs to /usr/share/logstash/logs which is now configured via log4j2.properties
[2018-03-28T22:42:53,484][INFO ][logstash.modules.scaffold] Initializing module {:module_name=>"fb_apache", :directory=>"/usr/share/logstash/modules/fb_apache/configuration"}
[2018-03-28T22:42:53,515][INFO ][logstash.modules.scaffold] Initializing module {:module_name=>"netflow", :directory=>"/usr/share/logstash/modules/netflow/configuration"}
[2018-03-28T22:42:54,222][WARN ][logstash.config.source.multilocal] Ignoring the 'pipelines.yml' file because modules or command line options are specified
[2018-03-28T22:42:55,092][INFO ][logstash.runner          ] Starting Logstash {"logstash.version"=>"6.2.3"}
[2018-03-28T22:42:55,795][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Successfully started Logstash API endpoint {:port=>9600}
[2018-03-28T22:42:58,225][INFO ][logstash.pipeline        ] Starting pipeline {:pipeline_id=>"main", "pipeline.workers"=>4, "pipeline.batch.size"=>125, "pipeline.batch.delay"=>50}
[2018-03-28T22:42:58,407][INFO ][logstash.pipeline        ] Pipeline started succesfully {:pipeline_id=>"main", :thread=>"#<Thread:0x35d85de2 run>"}
[2018-03-28T22:42:58,559][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Pipelines running {:count=>1, :pipelines=>["main"]}
[2018-03-28T22:42:58,867][INFO ][logstash.pipeline        ] Pipeline has terminated {:pipeline_id=>"main", :thread=>"#<Thread:0x35d85de2 run>"}
```

Adding `--log.level=debug` gives at lot more: the same as previous command, plus a lot more, including the following message-related log:

```
[2018-03-28T22:44:30,671][DEBUG][logstash.pipeline        ] filter received {"event"=>{"@timestamp"=>2018-03-28T22:44:30.567Z, "sequence"=>1, "@version"=>"1", "message"=>"Hello world!", "host"=>"5e26a941934f"}}
[2018-03-28T22:44:30,679][DEBUG][logstash.pipeline        ] output received {"event"=>{"@timestamp"=>2018-03-28T22:44:30.567Z, "sequence"=>1, "@version"=>"1", "message"=>"Hello world!", "host"=>"5e26a941934f"}}
[2018-03-28T22:44:30,680][DEBUG][logstash.pipeline        ] filter received {"event"=>{"@timestamp"=>2018-03-28T22:44:30.568Z, "sequence"=>2, "@version"=>"1", "message"=>"Hello world!", "host"=>"5e26a941934f"}}
...
```

Lots of noise but it will be useful when tracking down an error.

### Problem

I had trouble directly capturing the stdout and stderr of the `logstash` command in my program, but anyway, I find it easier to ask Logstash to directly write to a log file.

According to [the documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/running-logstash-command-line.html#command-line-flags) adding the `--path.logs=/tmp` to the `logstash` command should make it write log file to `/tmp` but it does not. I get no log file in `/tmp` after the following command ends (nor during it executes):

```
logstash \
    --path.logs=/tmp \
    --log.level=debug \
    -e "input { generator { count => 3 } } output { null {} }"
```

So: How make logstash write it's log messages (not the data it processes) to a file?

Comment: Have you tried to use the [setting file](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/logstash-settings-file.html)? Perhaps it would work better that way.

Comment: I've set `log.level: debug` and `path.logs: /tmp/logstash-logs` into the `/etc/logstash/logstash.yml`, created the `/tmp/logstash-logs` directory (with 777 permissions) and executed `logstash -e "input { generator { count => 3 } } output { null {} }"`. `logstash` outputs confirms it took the changes into account (_Sending Logstash's logs to /tmp/logstash-logs which is now configured via log4j2.properties_) but still no log files.

Comment: I have no other idea. And I don't remember what was done in production last time I deployed LS (and I've since changed of companies). If you don't get an answer here, perhaps you could try their forums: https://discuss.elastic.co/

Comment: Done, we'll see :)